# JWT authentification in react native

Tags: react-native, jwt, react-native-keychain

As a React-Native beginner, I follow this tutorial to implement JWT authentification : https://blog.logrocket.com/react-native-jwt-authentication-using-axios-interceptors/

Unfortunately, the result is the following :
Keychain Error: Cannot read property 'getGenericPasswordForOptions' of null
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAuthState' of null]
at App.js:null in loadJWT

Does anyone have an idea to solve this error ?
NB : I use Expo...
Thanks in advance

I tried to re-install react-native-keychain as Bing IA suggested, but still the same...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The backend is there : https://github.com/cristian-rita/express-jwt-authentication

Comment: And the frontend : https://github.com/cristian-rita/react-native-jwt-example